# Graphics plain 2D objects are not rendered while an action occurred

Tags: swing

I am designing a game in Swing. Currently I am designing the maze for this game. The maze is generated by using Depth First Search algorithm. In my main JFrame, I have some JPanel. One JPanel, named mazePanel contains the maze. There are some other JPanel also, which contains the JButton for controlling. Following is the mazePanel code.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MazePanel extends JPanel {

    private MazeGenerator mazeGenerator;
    private boolean startNewMaze = false;

    public MazePanel() {
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Maze"));
        setToolTipText("This is the maze");
    }

    public void addNewMaze() {
        startNewMaze = true;
        mazeGenerator = new MazeGenerator();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (startNewMaze) {
            mazeGenerator.generate(g);
            startNewMaze = false;
        }
    }
}
```

There is one JButton, which calls the method mazePanel.addNewMaze() and set the Boolean startNewMaze to true. After setting the startNewMaze, maze should be generated. i.e. mazeGenerator.generate(g) is inside if() condition. Method mazeGenerator.generate(g) recursively draw the random maze. That is why I don’t want to run this method not more than once.

Up to this everything is looking fine. But while I am running the main JFrame and clicks on the JButton, maze is not rendered in the mazePanel. Sometimes when I minimize and maximize the JFrame, maze rendered (might be because of repaint() occur). Even if I comment mazeGenerator.generate(g) inside if() condition and put some g.drawString(). The string is not rendered while action performed (i.e.Pressing JButton).

Where is the problem? Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: don't ever change the state of any component while painting it. Instead, change the state and then trigger the revalidation/painting, f.i. in addNewMaze

Comment: Hi kleopatra. Thank you for your kind response. It would be best if you can explain me a little bit.

Comment: no idea what there might be to explain, beyond "move the maze.generate() from the paintComponent to some other method, f.i. into addNewMaze"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically you have a `JPanel` which contains nothing, you call a method unknown to Swing and expects the `paintComponent` method is magically called when you change the state of a private field.

You already discovered that minimizing and maximizing again solves your problem due to a repaint. That should be sufficient information to know you have to trigger a repaint yourself when you press that button.

If you would have followed the suggestion from @kleopatra to, and I quote,

> change the state and then trigger the revalidation/painting

you would already have solved your problem